# How to calculate how many seconds is remained to any time with 5 or 0 in its minutes in js?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to know exactly how many seconds I have left till the clock get to a time which has 5 or 0 in its minutes such as 11:00 , 11:05, 10:55, 8:35 or any other number that has the aforementioned digits in it.

For example if it is now 6:32:14 and of course time should be calculated dynamically, I wish to know how many seconds do I have left to 6:35.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the last digit of the minutes to deduce whether the next multiple of five will end in 5 or 10.

```js
const date = new Date;
const minutes = date.getMinutes() % 10;
const seconds = date.getSeconds();
const nextTime = minutes < 5 ? 5 : 10;
const secondsLeft = nextTime * 60 - minutes * 60 - seconds;
console.log(secondsLeft);
```